# Rename files based on folder name

Tags: macos, terminal, regex, rename

I have lots of `index.html` files in unique named folders (one per folder).
I wish to rename each file with that of it's parent folder name.

From:

```
/folder1/index.html
/folder2/index.html
/folder3/index.html
/folder4/index.html
/folder5/index.html
```

To:

```
/folder1/folder1.html
/folder2/folder2.html
/folder3/folder3.html
/folder4/folder4.html
/folder5/folder5.html
```

#### Attempt 1

I have tried `rename -vn 's:(/[^/]*)/[^/]*$:$1$1.html:' folder/*/*.html` which returns with:

```
Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.18'; s:(/[^/]*)/[^/]*$:$1$1.html: }
'folder/*/*.html' unchanged
```

I don't really understand what's happening to be able to fix it.

#### Attempt 2

Next, I tried `rename -n -v '...' folder/*/*.html`, which returned with:

```
Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.18'; ... }
Unimplemented at (eval 2) line 1.
```

I am using OSX with [**rename**](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/3c6951ca3072c76af19d096e1332c31de07426c6/Library/Formula/rename.rb) installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works for me:

```
rename -vn 's/([^\/]+)\/index/$1\/$1/' folder*/*.html
```

Prints:

```
folder1/index.html renamed as folder1/folder1.html
folder2/index.html renamed as folder2/folder2.html
folder3/index.html renamed as folder3/folder3.html
folder4/index.html renamed as folder4/folder4.html
folder5/index.html renamed as folder5/folder5.html
```

Another solution with `sed`:

```
ls -1 folder*/*.html | sed 's/\([^\/]\+\)\/index.html/mv "\0" "\1\/\1.html"/'
```

Prints:

```
mv "folder1/index.html" "folder1/folder1.html"
mv "folder2/index.html" "folder2/folder2.html"
mv "folder3/index.html" "folder3/folder3.html"
mv "folder4/index.html" "folder4/folder4.html"
mv "folder5/index.html" "folder5/folder5.html"
```

If that prints the correct commands just pipe it to a `bash`. But first make sure that the printed commands would work before executing it:

```
ls -1 folder*/*.html | sed 's/\([^\/]\+\)\/index.html/mv "\0" "\1\/\1.html"/' | bash
```

Comment: I still get `Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.18'; s/([^\/]+)\/index/$1\/$1/ }
'folder*/*.html' unchanged`. Not sure why. I have even reinstalled rename.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Do you have perl installed? Then you could just use that rename utillity: http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt. I don't know your homebrew rename utillity posted in your question.

Comment: I don't have perl installed. I checked the code for homebrew rename and they are very similar. Without `-v` I don't get any output (which is obvious to me now, even with `-n` enabled).

Comment: @evolutionxbox see my edit, I added a 2nd solution

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
for in in `find . -name index.html -type f`
do
bname=$(dirname $i|sed 's:/::g')
mv $i $(dirname $i)/${bname}.html
done
```

P.S. this will work only with one level of directories and files with extension .html